# using FreeRDP disk redirection

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, rdp, samba, ubuntu-unity, freerdp

I'm on an Ubuntu machine (client) RDP'ing into another Ubuntu machine (server). I'd like to access my client's home dir from within my server session.

From what I can tell, this is done with "disk redirection".

I've tried this (I've excluded all the other params):

```
xfreerdp /drive:localhome,/home/james
```

I assume that somehow I'd be able to access "localhome" in the server. Do I need to share this with samba on the client first?

I've seen some people reference it like:

```
\\tsclient\localhome
```

The doc is thin on this and there looks to be about 4 different command line syntaxes for freerdp. I think "/drive" is the latest.

What am I missing, I feel I'm close.

Both client and server are Ubuntu 12.04. Client is FreeRDP version 1.2.0-beta1

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to make changes to the remote desktop code? If you are just trying to change the configuration settings without changing the code, then you should ask on SuperUser.com, ubuntu.stackexchange.com, or unix.stackexchange.com. StackOverflow is only for programming questions.

Comment: Thanks, but I gave up on FreeRDP, it doesn't work very well with MS Terminal Server. I'll try and figure out which stackexchange site to use going forward. I didn't think it mattered since it was tagged.